# How to fix this python %s placeholder arrangement

Tags: python, placeholder

I need to iterate through input file pairs, *R1* and *R2*, which will be processed together and each appended with a ".trim" file extension.

I have a limited knowledge of python and glob, which have worked well for similar tasks using paired inputs but a single output. I am completely stumped as to why this doesn't work, though I'm sure it's an easy fix.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob("ATAC*R1*.fastq.gz")
for ifile in files:
        os.system("cutadapt -a CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -A CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -a AGATGTGTATAAGAGA -o %s.trim -p %s.trim %s %s" % (ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2"), ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2"))
```

```
Error: 
 line 7

                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This should work as follows:

```
ATAC2-1_R1_.fastq.gz and ATAC2-1_R1_.fastq.gz -> ATAC2-1_R1_.fastq.gz.trim and ATAC2-1_R1_.fastq.gz.trim.
```

There are several R1 and R2 pairs that I would like to iterate through.Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you have a non-printing character on the last line of the script.

Comment: Why do you think the problem has anything to do with the `%s` placeholders? The error message says it's on line 7, but the placeholders are on line 6.

Comment: Usually Python displays a pointer to the syntax error with `^`. Is that really the whole error message?

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses! I foolishly left out a parenthesis which went unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue is that you're missing an ending parenthesis:

```
    os.system("cutadapt -a CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -A CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -a AGATGTGTATAAGAGA -o %s.trim -p %s.trim %s %s" % (ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2"), ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2")))
```

You just need to add the ending parenthesis and you should stop experiencing that syntax error.

Comment: Don't post real answers to typo questions, just post a comment. The answer slows down the hoover that deletes bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do this with %s placeholders, I would try .format(), like so:

```
"cutadapt -a CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -A CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT -a AGATGTGTATAAGAGA -o {0}.trim -p {1}.trim {2} {3}".format(ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2"), ifile, ifile.replace("R1","R2"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. This will be great to practice with!